# Snowflake ifnull and parse_json when combined it is not working as expected

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-task

This is my query

> select object_construct('id', id, alpha, PARSE_JSON(null)) from tablename
> limit 1

the output is { "id" :1, "alpha":null }

but when I combined **parse_json** with **ifnull** it returns empty object **{}** not working as expected

> select object_construct('id',IFNULL(id, (PARSE_JSON(null)), alpha,
> IFNULL(alpha, (PARSE_JSON(null))) from tablename limit 1

the above returns {}

but I need to have the null values { "id" : 1, "alpha" : null }

combining is not working any solutions?

**[Question Updated]**

Thanks Felipe Hoffa.

In Your answer, the last part is working as expected.

```
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('id', id, 'alpha', IFNULL(alpha, PARSE_JSON('null')))
FROM (SELECT 1 id, null alpha)
# {"alpha": null, "id": 1}
```

But When I try with the below, it is not Working

```
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
'id', id, 
'alpha', IFNULL(alpha, PARSE_JSON('null'))
 ) 
FROM (SELECT id, alpha from tableName)
#{ "id" :1 }
```

it works, when using your FROM query : **FROM (SELECT 1 id, null alpha)**

not working, when using my FROM query : **FROM (SELECT id, alpha from tableName)**

Hope cleared.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to use IS_NULL_VALUE to test for a null in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

> *I need to have the null values { "id" : 1, "alpha" : null }*

You could use [OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct_keep_null.html) instead of [OBJECT_CONSTRUCT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html).

```
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL('id', id, 'alpha', alpha) from tableName;

SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL(*) from (SELECT id, alpha from tableName) sub;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the first statement of the question is not true. When encoding `PARSE_JSON(null)`, `null` is not represented:

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('id', id, alpha, PARSE_JSON(null))
FROM (SELECT 1 id, null alpha)

# {"id": 1}
```

To fix this, you have to do `PARSE_JSON('null')` instead -- and quote the name of the variable:

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('id', id, 'alpha', PARSE_JSON('null'))
FROM (SELECT 1 id, null alpha)

# {"alpha": null, "id": 1}
```

That looks better. With that solved, now `IF_NULL` will work as desired:

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('id', id, 'alpha', IFNULL(alpha, PARSE_JSON('null')))
FROM (SELECT 1 id, null alpha)

# {"alpha": null, "id": 1}
```

Comment: SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('id', id, 'alpha', IFNULL(alpha, PARSE_JSON('null')))
FROM (SELECT 1 id, null alpha) this is working.

but not from 
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('id', id, 'alpha', IFNULL(alpha, PARSE_JSON('null')))
FROM (SELECT  id, alpha from tableName)
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what the previous comment means

Comment: SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('id', id, 'alpha', IFNULL(alpha, PARSE_JSON('null'))) FROM (SELECT 1 id, null alpha)
 THIS IS WORKING FINE .

but when I try "column name with tablename" it is not working in snowflake(not showing NULL values)
.
example below 
 SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('id', id, 'alpha', IFNULL(alpha, PARSE_JSON('null'))) FROM (SELECT id, alpha from tableName)

Comment: " FROM (SELECT id, alpha from tableName) " when I try with this it now working as expected.